# How can i remove small notification when use Media Projection for screen recording?

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

Can i remove small notification when use Media Projection for screen recording or screen capture ?
[Notification Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NId3O.png)

Comment: That icon tells the person using the device that the screen can be seen by other devices. In my opinion, the ability to remove this would be a security issue.

Comment: I too think the notification is compulsive of android security permision But still want to know  ?

Comment: Have you came across any solution yet?

Comment: @DeepDave . Hi . I have already stupid solution , its draw and make one status bar with so many thing (battery , network , wifi , clock ...) to cover system status bar ... But , it's may be not working on newest android version (8.0) .

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.
I am taking screenshot from background i need to hide this symbol :|
Have a great day

Comment: @DeepDave did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: IMO It will be there unless you switch to demo mode as per accepted answer but you can not do it programatically for someone else's device.

Comment: @DeepDave, I also want to create android background service to take screenshot. Any reference link would be great help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there is actually an option called 'Demo mode' under 'Developer settings', you get full WIFI signal , full network bar and full battery icon, any other icon will be ignored.

It's only available on Android M+
[image]

Comment: I don't see that in my version of android (6.0) - is that new?

Comment: I think it's called 'System UI tuner' on 6.0

Comment: I can see plenty of articles - but I guess LG has stripped that feature from my phone :( Have a +1 though - this is a good feature.

Comment: Yeah, some manufacturers can possibly stripe those features away, annoying :(

Comment: I can't find System UI tuner Setting on Samsung S7 (android 6.01). It depend on  Device ?

Comment: I don't own a S7 so my guess will be Samsung probably removed it as well. You can try on a Nexus device if you have one.

Comment: @YoungKing No problem, please accept as answer if this solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Cast icon is still shown even if I enable demo mode